# NoClassFoundException: for ByteOutputStream

Tags: java, wildfly

I am deploying a web application built in **jre7** on **wildfly9**. In my application I have functionality to return image from a location from server to client. I have first fetched that image from the location then converted it to byte[] using **ByteOutputStream**. I am having **NoClassFoundException** for ByteOutputStream while ByteOutputStream is a **jre7** class and exists in **rt.jar**. My code works properly in local tomcat7 server.

Comment: Make sure the Jar you are building is an Uber / shaded jar.

Answer (score 0):

When you compile your application, you need to have classes that your application uses/refers to in your development environment compile classpath, if you don't (do that) then a compile-time error will occur.
When you run your compiled application, you need to have all classes that your application uses/refers to in your JVM class path or included in your application package, if you don't (do that) then a run-time error will occur.

So make sure you are packaging all the dependencies while building your jar.

Comment: the jar is not added by me. it is inbuilt jar in jre7. also i have checked the jre7 folder of my server rt.jar exists and also the ByteOutputStream class.

Comment: Hello I have resolved the issue by adding an external jar for ByteOutputStream. But did not understand why wildfly is not finding the only class in rt.jar itself whlie I am able to do so in tomcat 7 server.